# Java Inheritance: Why is it not calling the method of the subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

I'm wondering why Java is calling the subclass method with the mA() method but not with the im(b) method.
I can't really see any reason why it's doing that.
How does Java decide which method to call?

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new B();

        a.mA();  // prints BmA
        a.im(b);  // prints Aim  --  Why not Bim?
        b.im(a);  // prints Aim  -- Why not Bim?
    }
}


public class A {
    public void mA() {System.out.println("AmA");};
    public void im(A a) {System.out.println("Aim");};
}


public class B extends A {
    public void mA() {System.out.println("BmA");};
    public void im(B b) {System.out.println("Bim");};
}
```

I would expect im(b) to behave like mA().

Comment: ehm ... no, if you want the im(B b) to be called, you need to call it on a variable that's declared as an element of B. a might be instantiated as one, but it still is declared as an element of A

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I know that, but I wanna know why Java is doing it this way if I declare it as a B.

Comment: @DanielF.M. because there you pass an A, while in the method in B, you expect one of type B. You didn't override, but overload your method

Comment: @Lino why does b.im(a) not print 'Bim' then? Java knows that A a is an instance of B, therefore I would expect b.im(a) to print 'Bim'.

Comment: @DanielF.M. because that method expects an instance of B as parameter, yet you pass an instance of A

Comment: Alright, I got it now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the argument type.

im(B b) does not override im(A a)

See: https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/overriding-and-overloading-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know that it's an instance of `B`, so it doesn't know that `B.im(B)` is a candidate to be called there.

It does know that it's an instance of `A`, and that there's a method called `im`, which takes a single parameter of type `A`; since a `B` is a instance of `A` also, that's the method it invokes.

Comment: It knows about mA(). Why is it not possible to assume that it also knows about im(b)?

Comment: There is a method called `mA` on `A` which takes no parameters; and `B.mA()` overrides `A.mA()`, so the subclass method is invoked. `B.im(B)` doesn't override `A.im(A)`, because the parameters are of different types.

Answer (score 1):

The methods im(A) and im(B) are not override-equivalent. If you try to annotate im(B) with @Override you will get a compiler error. Only methods with the same signature are override-equivalent. The signature of a method consists of the name and the parameter type(s). The parameter types in your example are different, even if B inherits A.

If you want to realize this, you can just change the parameter type to Object, which has the disadvantage that it is not type safe. For a type safe solution you have to use generics.

Comment: In the wording of the JLS, the requirement is that it has to be a *subsignature*, see [8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1): "The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA."

Comment: @Hulk You can only override methods with exactly the same signature. The only thing u can change is return type but only if it is a subtype. I can't see what is wrong with that.

Comment: The other thing you can change is the generic type of parameters - they ony need to have the same erasure (I admit that this is not relevant here). I was only nit-picking, this is a good answer (already upvoted).